# Как получить вводимые значения в PyQt (5)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Имеется простое клиент-серверное приложение, пытаюсь прикрутить к нему графику.
Клиент посылает 2 числа и знак действия на сервер и получает обратно результат.

Я сделал 4 идентичные по логике кнопки: (3 для ввода 1 для результата)

```
def initUI(self):
    self.btn = QPushButton('Dialog', self) #окно диалога с кнопкой для старта ввода
    self.btn.move(20, 20)
    self.btn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)

    self.value_a = QLineEdit(self) #первая полосочка и таких еще 3.
    self.value_a.move(150, 22)


def showDialog(self):
    int, oka = QInputDialog.getInt(self, 'Input Dialog','Enter your VALA:')    
    if oka:
        #МЕТКА
        self.vala.setText(str(int)) 
        #МЕТКА
```

Ввожу цифру и на экране в полоске отображается, но как получить ее значение чтобы затем можно было передать?

====

```
text, okd = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Input Dialog','Enter + - / *')
if okd:
    self.do.setText(str(text)) #знак действия = тексту или как его обозначить можно?
```

нашел способ такой: txt_a = self.value_a.text()  но при втыкании этого кода в `#МЕТКА` при последующем запуске программа вылетает после ввода//либо на print(txt_a) выдает None

//=== upd ====

```
import pickle #клиент
import socket

class Ops:
    a = None
    b = None
    op = None

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))
while 1:
    ops = Ops()
    ops.a = input("a= ")
    ops.b = input("b= ")
    ops.op = input("действие +; -; /; *  ")

    message = pickle.dumps(ops) #запаковал и отослал
    sock.send(message)

    data = sock.recv(1024) #получаю результат действия
    res = data.decode()
    print(res)

sock.close()
```

## ====сервер====VVV

```
import socket
import pickle

class Ops:
    a = None
    b = None
    op = None

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_address = ('localhost', 9090)
print('  {} порт таков: {}'.format(*server_address))
sock.bind(server_address)

sock.listen(1)

while True:

    print('waiting for a connection')
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        print('подключение от', client_address)

        while True:
            data = connection.recv(1024)

            ops = pickle.loads(data)
            print(ops.a, ops.b, ops.op)
            if data:
                print('отправляю Клиенту')
                expression = ops.a + ops.op + ops.b #выполняю действие
                print(expression)
                result = eval(expression) 
                connection.sendall(str(result).encode())#посылаю результат
            else:
                print('пусто', client_address)
                break

    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Т.е. нужен минимальный код, воспроизводящий проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример с кнопками, диалогами и с отловом внезапных падений (`log_uncaught_exceptions`):

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    quit()


import sys
sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.le_num1 = QLineEdit()
        self.pb_num1 = QPushButton('...')
        self.pb_num1.clicked.connect(self.show_dialog_num1)

        self.le_num2 = QLineEdit()
        self.pb_num2 = QPushButton('...')
        self.pb_num2.clicked.connect(self.show_dialog_num2)

        self.le_op = QLineEdit()
        self.pb_op = QPushButton('...')
        self.pb_op .clicked.connect(self.show_dialog_op)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        layout.addWidget(QLabel('num1'), 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.le_num1, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.pb_num1, 0, 2)

        layout.addWidget(QLabel('num2'), 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.le_num2, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.pb_num2, 1, 2)

        layout.addWidget(QLabel('op'), 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.le_op, 2, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.pb_op, 2, 2)

    def show_dialog_num1(self):
        value, ok = QInputDialog.getInt(self, 'Input dialog', 'Enter your num1:')
        if not ok:
            return

        self.le_num1.setText(str(value))

    def show_dialog_num2(self):
        value, ok = QInputDialog.getInt(self, 'Input dialog', 'Enter your num2:')
        if not ok:
            return

        self.le_num2.setText(str(value))

    def show_dialog_op(self):
        value, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Input dialog', 'Enter + - / *')
        if not ok:
            return

        self.le_op.setText(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = Window()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.** Судя по вашей задаче, можно сделать форму проще:

- [QLineEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qLineedit.html) для значений заменить на [QSpinBox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html) / [QDoubleSpinBox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html)
- [QLineEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qLineedit.html) для знака операции поменять на [QComboBox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html)
- Убрать вызов диалогов ввода значений - они будут не нужны, т.к. на форме уже будут специализированные виджеты

Тогда, можно будет упростить форму и использовать другой компоновщик и получится такой код:

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.sb_num1 = QSpinBox()
        self.sb_num2 = QSpinBox()

        self.cb_op = QComboBox()
        self.cb_op.addItems(['+', '-', '/', '*'])

        layout = QFormLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
        layout.addRow('num1', self.sb_num1)
        layout.addRow('num2', self.sb_num2)
        layout.addRow('op', self.cb_op)
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, 2й метод прям очень глаз радует - ато нашел лишь громоздкий пример с диалогом. Но так и не смог уловить как сохранить значение что я ввел в переменную. В консольном варианте я разобрался пакую вот так: (код не влез, воткнул клиент-сервера коды в основной пост)

Comment: Если помогло, примите ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

В Qt creator-e можно сделать так .

```
QString str = ui->lineEdit->text();
int cifra = str.toInt();
qDebug() << "cifra: " << cifra;
```